# How can I exclude classes from a Grails 3 plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, gradle, grails-plugin, grails-3.0

I'm trying to convert a Grails 2 plugin to Grails 3 and I have trouble excluding a couple of domain classes that are used in tests only from the resulting jar.

The [documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/plugins.html) states:

> in your build.gradle you should exclude the compiled classes from the JAR file:

```
jar {
    exclude "com/demo/**/**"
}
```

...but if I try this I get the following error from Gradle: 
`Could not find method jar() for arguments [build_64zizslf5a7zfo329yz5tdsoi$_run_closure1@566c53c] on root project '...'`

I can post the entire stack trace but it doesn't look very helpful. I'm using Gradle 2.3, provided by the default Gradle wrapper that the `create-plugin` command generates. I also haven't made any other changes to `build.gradle` because my plugin doesn't require any external dependencies.

Comment: Have you also used `pluginExcludes` in the descriptor as mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: Yes - alone it does nothing (files are still included in the JAR), as soon as I put the `jar{..}` block into `build.gradle` the build fails. And not just the JAR task: I cannot use any gradle tasks while the block is in there, the whole build file is considered invalid.

Comment: If the `jar` method can't be found when your build is run then I expect that something is out of place elsewhere in your build file.  See my answer below which links to a working solution.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/excludesdemo.  That includes 2 domain classes under https://github.com/jeffbrown/excludesdemo/tree/master/grails-app/domain.

The top level `build.gradle` file at https://github.com/jeffbrown/excludesdemo/blob/72896a3f88f617d530bbdde8976d5bfe8d1e820a/build.gradle#L73 contains the following:

```
jar {
    exclude 'package1/**'
}
```

When you run `./gradlew jar` you should see that the jar file generated at `build/libs/excludesdemo-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` does contain `package2/Author.class` and does not contain `package1/Person.class`.

Comment: Thank you - my problem was that the jar block appeared too early in the build file and I realised this as soon as I saw your example. I guess I was thinking declaratively, as in order of directives doesn't matter, while Gradle works procedurally and some plugin must first be loaded before the jar block actually 'means' anything.

Comment: "my problem was that the jar block appeared too early in the build file" - I see.  Where you can put it depends on what plugins are being applied.  In that particular example, I think it would work anywhere after the `spring-boot` plugin is applied at https://github.com/jeffbrown/excludesdemo/blob/72896a3f88f617d530bbdde8976d5bfe8d1e820a/build.gradle#L25